# Newbie Question - Changing it to port 80 & custom URL

Tags: docker, url, web-hosting, port80

I am a noob in all of this but I am learning about hosting web applications etc.

I have installed iPeer on my Ubuntu Server, more info on iPeer feel free to check it out here https://github.com/ubc/iPeer/.

I realize iPeer is using docker containers and i have no prior knowledge on dockers structure or anything remotely close to the word docker.

Once I have installed iPeer, iPeer is on 8080 port and I want to switch it to port 80.

My second question would be editing the url and making it cool like localhost/iPeerapp

Is it all possible to make iPeer listen on port 80 and as well having to change the URL to localhost/iPeerapp listening on port 80?

Any more follow up information please let me know. I am active on this site

Answer (score 0):

> Once I have installed iPeer, iPeer is on 8080 port and I want to switch it to port
> One option is to publish port `80` on the host, so you will able to access the container using port `80`

```
docker run -it --rm -p 80:8080 my_docker_image
```

Or the other option is to use Nginx which will solve both requirements.

- Port
- Path `localhost/ipeerapp`

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  nginx:
   image: nginx:alpine
   volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
   ports:
     - 80:80
   depends_on:
     - ipeer
  ipeer:
    image: iPeer
```

Where define a rule in Nginx to rewrite.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /ipeerapp/ {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://ipeer:8080;
        }
    }
```

I did not verify the Nginx config, but the other way to deal with your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give it a go and provide feedback soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt work for me as when i config the file in nginx.conf to what you gave me and changing the port in docker-compse.yml i got an error when starting up docker (docker-compose up -d command).. stating the port/address is already in use